# ListFragment displays wrong items

Tags: android

I am new to the android api and I have some problems with .. the basics.
I'm trying to get a list working, but the list displays the wrong text:

Each row has two TextViews (title, subtitle), heres the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_title"
        android:text="SUBTITLE"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I extend ListFragment (I need this fragment thing, because of a slidingMenu library), have a custom adapter and an item class.
in the onActivityCreated() method I add some random items to the adapter:

```
package com.slidingmenu.example;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            adapter.add(new SampleItem(new Fragment(), "title no. " + i, "some subtitle"));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class SampleItem {
        public Fragment frag;
        public String title;
        public String subTitle;
        public SampleItem(Fragment frag, String title, String subTitle) {
            this.frag = frag; 
            this.title = title; 
            this.subTitle = subTitle;
        }
    }

    public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

        public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            TextView subTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_subtitle);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

So I thougt that the list would display something like this:

```
title no. 0
some subtitle
-
title no. 1
some subtitle
-
title no. 2
some subtitle
-

etc.
```

but instead it just displays what I defined in the row.xml:

```
TITLE
SUBTITLE
-
TITLE
SUBTITLE
-

etc.
```

I think getView() needs to be changed (at least it doesn't make to much sense to me) but I'm not sure. 
Everything I try results in some nullpointer exception or worse.

Please, can someone tell me what I need to change?

Comment: well, you never call textview.settext(sampleitem.title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is int the Adapter:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            TextView subTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_subtitle);

            return convertView;
        }
```

the `getView` never fills up the `title` and `subtitle`. Second you never submit to the `superclass` the dataset you want to show in the `ListFragment`.

Here you have to ways. Or you ovveride the `getCount` and `getItem` and `getItemId` methods, or feed up the superclass with the dataset, using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) constructor. Read carefully the documentation.

Comment: ah, I added title.setText(this.getItem(position).title);
   subTitle.setText(this.getItem(position).subTitle); and now it works. i thought i allready tried that. thank you anyway!